# Tracking Ajax Form in Google Tag Manager

Tags: ajax, forms, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, marketo

I have a simple form landing page built in Marketo. The form uses Ajax. The traditional Form trigger won't work, neither will History Change. What should be so simple is getting overly-complicated.

Clicks on the Submit Button is tracking but that is not accurate since form requires validation.

Any ideas on getting a Tag to fire on successful form submit so I can track form leads in Google Analytics?

Much appreciated!

Comment: are you using forms 2.0?

Comment: Look into using the jquery ajaxComplete function.

Answer (score 1):

Check :

1. Form submit fires valid **submit** browser event.
2. This event must be propagated to **document** node.

Depending on this you need to create Custom HTML tag in Google Tag Manager with JavaScript code with your custom event listener. Implementation depends on either there is no form submit event (1) or event isn't propagated (2).

Read nice blog post on the topic by Simo Agava:

http://www.simoahava.com/analytics/track-form-engagement-with-google-tag-manager/

Comment: Thanks so much for your response. From my understanding of the article, changes would need to be made to the form page. We do not have access and cannot expect any updates there. Are they any other methods that might work?

Comment: @SMG, you can use Custom HTML tag in Google Tag Manager to include your custom JavaScript Code.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using Forms 2.0, then use the documentation provided here:

http://developers.marketo.com/documentation/websites/forms-2-0/

The following setup worked for me. Create a Custom HTML tag like this in Tag Manager:

```
<script>
MktoForms2.whenReady(function (form) {
    form.onSubmit(function(){
        dataLayer.push({
            'event': 'hello',
            'message': 'world'
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Create a trigger that makes sense in your case. We are using these forms on Marketo landing pages, so I set the tag to fire whenever the URL matches the pattern we use for our landing pages.

On form submit you should see this pushed to the `dataLayer` (I had to furiously hit the `esc` key on my keyboard to keep the page from refreshing so I could make sure this was pushed to the `dataLayer`).

The documentation shows you can also use `onSuccess` as an event as well.

This setup was inspired by slide #46 here: http://www.slideshare.net/stijnheijthuijsen/marketo-user-group-nl-20150209-hands-on-google-analytics

Comment: Thanks for this. Are there any simpler to implement methods for tracking, such as upon history change?

Comment: There won't be any simpler methods because of the way the Marketo form is built.